# Nodejs kafka consumer infinite loop

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, mq

I am running kafka_2.11-2.0.0 on ubuntu 16.04 machine. Created a topic and produced some messages to it from command line interface.

[image]

And started consumer from command line, it's consuming well.

[image]

But when I started nodejs consumer like below, it's infinitely iterating. Is there anything I was missing in my client code?

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
client = new kafka.Client(),
consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [
        {topic: 'mytopic', partition: 0}
    ],
    {
        autoCommit: true
    }
);
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
});
consumer.on('error', function (err){
        console.log(err);

})
consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit();
})
```

Here is the output.

```js
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message2',
  offset: 1,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message3',
  offset: 2,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message2',
  offset: 1,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message3',
  offset: 2,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message2',
  offset: 1,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: 'message3',
  offset: 2,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: null }
{ topic: 'mytopic',
  value: '',
  offset: 0,
  partition: 0,
  highWaterOffset: 3,
  key: '' }
```

Comment: Try consumer group, not low level consumer https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#consumergroup

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that the issue with kafka new release 2.0.0. So I moved to previous version and it's working now.